# Cassandra/Scylla on docker without internet in linux server

Tags: docker, cassandra, containers, datastax, scylla

I have installed docker on redhat/centos server. docker services are running fine but how I can install or build cassandra/scylla image on docker. my server is not connected with internet so while building cassandra/scylla image or run then getting below error "Unable to find image" with timeout exception.

Can anyone help how to build cassandra/Scylla docker image without internet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you download the image though, it is very simple to take it offline and load it into an offline system using `docker save` to export the image as a file, and `docker load` to import the image back into docker.

Comment: can you put here the steps and image link. it will really helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: There is no image link. You need to install docker on an internet-connected machine, do a `docker pull` and then save the pulled image using `docker save`. Once that is done, take the file to an offline machine with docker installed and `docker load` the image there

Comment: If it is the link for the docker hub here it is: `https://hub.docker.com/r/scylladb/scylla/`

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not seem to be related to Apache Cassandra or Scylla.
You do need access to Docker hub to download the relevant image for the first time, for example when running `docker run hello-world`

Once you solve that, you can move to run Apache Cassandra or Scylla with, for example with

```
docker run --name some-scylla -d scylladb/scylla
```

Comment: @Tzack, its related with cassandra and scylla cause I am asking about cassandra/scylla image offline for docker. it will really helpful to me if you can share the steps or any documents. Thanks

Comment: It is the same steps as this: `https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/05/23/how-to-save-and-load-docker-images/` 
but use the container from scylla.